# Limits of square root function

Tags: limits

I'm having difficulty seeing the answer to:

$$
\lim_{x \to 3^+} \sqrt{x^2-9} 
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x \to 3^-} \sqrt{x^2-9} 
$$

Comment: Is the second thing the limit of the negative square root? Or th elimit as we approach $3$ from below?

Comment: not the negative square root but limit as we approach 3 from below

Comment: Take $\epsilon>0$ and write $3^+=3+\epsilon$ and $3^-=3-\epsilon$, now let $\epsilon\searrow 0$. Then use the fact that $\epsilon^2\ll \epsilon$ (i.e    $-2\epsilon+\epsilon^2<0$ in this particular situation)

Comment: What difficulty do you face ? Have you tried to apply the definition ?

Comment: **HINT** Note that as $x\to 3^+$, then $x^2 > 9$ and that as $x\to 3^-$, $x^2 < 9$. Then which one of your limits can not be defined?.

Comment: Yes, I understood that first limit, but not the second.  Now, I see that if x squared is less than 9 we would get undefined. Thank you